# Do I have to insert the foreign key values manually or PostgreSQL will automatically copy the value of the primary key into the second table?

Tags: postgresql

do i have to manually insert the FK to match the PK or this process can be automated? i'm using PostgreSQL.

if anyone can direct to me to a reference to this issue or a video tutorial explaining this, i would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to insert the value of the foreign key.

Comment: can it be automated or i have to do it manually, that's my question

Comment: You can create a trigger to do this. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-createconstraint.html

Comment: How could you possibly automate that? If you have e.g. an `orders` table and a `customers` table. How would you know to which customer an order should be linked to when you insert a new order?